# Box Cutter: cut mode not visible

Tags: modeling

Im trying to learn box cutter, but have a slight problem being that I can't see the cut box, like you normally can, as shown in picture 1 below.
I can only see the  information shown in picture 2, but no cut box.

Can someone help?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Box cutter is a third-party addon, not part of Blender so you'll have to ask on its web site or watch one of the many videos about it.